# elastic beanstalk php git eb command line configuaration

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my web application. I have successfully deployed my PHP/MYsql application by using git and the eb commmand line.

Every time I close and reopen the terminal to update my application the eb command is not recognised and I have to add it back it with the export command;

export PATH=$PATH:/eb/linux/python2.7/

I then have to go and add in all the Elastic Beanstalk configuration for my instance back in again.

Also I found that if I deploy another application and use the same path to the above eb folder, it overwrites the settings of the first application.

My question is firstly, how do I prevent having to add in eb and reconfigure my instance every time I reopen the terminal. And secondly, will each application have to point to a separate eb directory in order to separate the AWS configurations. i.e.

```
<path to unzipped EB CLI package>/app1/eb/linux/python2.7/
<path to unzipped EB CLI package>/app2/eb/linux/python2.7/
<path to unzipped EB CLI package>/app3/eb/linux/python2.7/
```

Comment: What OS are you developing on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what OS you're developing on, so here are several common options:

### Mac OSX

1. Open .bash_profile in your favorite text editor
2. Add `export PATH=$PATH:/eb/linux/python2.7/` to the bottom of this file
3. Save and close

### Ubuntu (possibly other *nix distros)

1. Open .bashrc in your favorite text editor
2. Add `export PATH=$PATH:/eb/linux/python2.7/` to the bottom of this file
3. Save and close

### Windows

1. Right click on My Computer
2. Click "Advanced System Settings" on the left hand side
3. Click "Environment Variables" at the bottom
4. In "System variables", find the row with "PATH"
5. Click the "Edit" button
6. Add ";/eb/linux/python2.7/" to the end of the "Variable Value" input
7. Click "Okay" repeatedly until all the dialog boxes are closed

Here's a [youtube video walkthrough to set environment variables in Windows](http://youtu.be/bEroNNzqlF4).